# I can't write line by line for send message (React, HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

(sorry for bad english) I'm coding a chat app using React but whenever I try to send line by line message (shift+enter for new line), it doesn't work. It just leaves spaces. But I press in two times to shift+enter, it works
Example:
I press shift+enter one time:

textarea:

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

after send message:

```
Line 1 Line 2
```

I press shift+enter twice (It works but I don't want this):

textarea:

```
Line1
// 1 line blank
Line2
```

message:

```
Line1
Line2
```

But I hate this. Please help me :( Here is code:

REACT:

```html
<textarea
  onInput={() => autoGrow}
  onChange={(e) => {
    setMessage(e.target.value);
  }}
  autoComplete="off"
  onKeyDown={sendMessage}
  type="text"
  className="overflow-y-auto rounded-l-2xl outline-none h-12 bg-dark-200 pt-3 text-white pl-4 justify-center resize-none flex items-center"
  placeholder="Text A Message"
  id="message-input"
  style={{ width: "90%", backgroundColor: "#323232" }}
>
</textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```js
// States
let [messages, setMessages] = useState([]),
    [ message, setMessage ] = useState("");
async function sendMessage(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (message.replace(/\s/g, "") === "") {
        return;
      } else {
        let data = {
          content: message.trim(),
          createdTimestamp: moment().locale("fr-FR").calendar(),
          id: generateID(),
        };
        setMessages([...messages, data]);
        setMessage("");
        e.target.value = "";
      }
    } else {
      setMessage(e.target.value);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You say the "message" displays incorrectly, but you have not shown the code that renders it.  Please do that.

Comment: message variable declared at the top @MattMorgan

Comment: @Drackin he means the code that displays the message